# I try to build android source, make clobber got some errors about "depends on disabled module"

Tags: android

I'm a newbie at aosp. I just following the guild on https://source.android.com/source/building.html in "preparing to build" section.
After I execute repo sync successfully, I run make clobber and got some errors:

```
ninja: no work to do.
[1/2] glob external/*/Android.bp
[1/1] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja 
out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build -t -b out/soong -d out/soong/build.ninja.d -o out/soong/build.ninja Android.bp
error: external/llvm/tools/gold/Android.bp:20:1: module "LLVMgold" variant "linux_x86_64_shared": depends on disabled module "libLLVM"
error: development/vndk/tools/vtable-dumper/Android.bp:17:1: module "vndk-vtable-dumper" variant "linux_x86_64": depends on disabled module "libLLVM"
error: external/llvm/tools/llvm-ar/Android.bp:5:1: module "llvm-ar" variant "linux_x86_64": depends on disabled module "libLLVM"
error: external/spirv-llvm/lib/SPIRV/Android.bp:22:1: module "libSPIRV" variant "linux_x86_64_shared": depends on disabled module "libLLVM"
error: frameworks/compile/libbcc/tools/bcc_strip_attr/Android.bp:19:1: module "bcc_strip_attr" variant "linux_x86_64": depends on disabled module "libLLVM"
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
23:55:27 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1
build/core/main.mk:24: recipe for target 'run_soong_ui' failed
make: *** [run_soong_ui] Error 1
```

I have no idea about this.It's looks like there are some disabled modules.How can I handle it? I just want to build aosp and import into Intellij Idea to read some java codes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  I had the same error when trying to compile using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `export FORCE_BUILD_LLVM_COMPONENTS=true` gets you past that...